# PHP Error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: php, libssl, pantheon, lando

I am working on a site using Lando and Pantheon and have recently been running into this error:

> php: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.0.0: cannot
>   open shared object file: No such file or directory

I don't know what caused it to start happening as I have been working on this site for weeks now without having this error. It is causing me to be unable to push or pull changes to Pantheon using Lando though. Any workaround or fix for this?

Comment: You're gonna have to look into your package manager / and its history. Either get the old dependency back, or get a matching php interpreter. Else consult your hoster.

Comment: This seems to be a problem with lando check this issue here: https://github.com/lando/lando/issues/1029

Comment: If you use php 7.1 it works.